# Gitolite denies access to a repo while allowing another

Tags: git, bash, gitolite

I have gitolite up and running and I work with it from multiple machines for quite a while. Therefore there are several of my 'rob' keys in gitolite-admin.
These days from this machine are awkward:

Part of my gotolite.conf

```
repo ProPro OpenTK-10Bit-test
    RW+     =   rob
```

Interestingly cloning ProPro to my Win8 desktop works, while a clone to OpenTK-10Bit-test is denied as if it was not there:

> Cloning into 'E:\src\OpenTk-10Bit-test'... FATAL: R any
>   OpenTk-10Bit-test rob DENIED by fallthru (or you mis-spelled the
>   reponame) fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Converseley I am committing from a Win7 machine for quite a while already.
What is going on?
Are there any bad characters?
There might be a difference that Win7 I use git from bash. But on my laptop I also access this repo with Tortoise from Win8.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Really bad: Do you know what actually happened? All went by Copy&Paste. So nothing should go wrong. BUT: Pasting a similar string in a combobox (TortoiseGit clone) switches to the similar string. So OpenTK... pasted always went to the previous mistake OpenTk...   Ohohoh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Windows is not case sensitive, Gitolite is, testing for the existence of the bare repo folder (see [`lib/Gitolite/Conf/Load.pm#L245-L250`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/4be7ac535c6135b373de70020de4d8874c7990a4/src/lib/Gitolite/Conf/Load.pm#L245-L250)).

> or you mis-spelled the reponame

If the `gitolite.conf` file allows access for `OpenTK-10Bit-test`, trying to clone `OpenTk-10Bit-test` ([as commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30903907/gitolite-denies-access-to-a-repo-while-allowing-another/30908417#comment49846509_30903907) by [And](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1576602/and)) will not work and will be denied.

Comment: Well, thanks. That was it. I tried my best varying the T in test and B as in Bit but did not see the k as Tk. But why does gitolite not complain about the spell mistake in the .conf file or why does it now work if I use "OpenTK-10Bit-test" . Solved but confused